# Создание новой базы с учетом таблиц предыдущей базы

Tags: база-данных, mysqli

Есть база данных, назовем ее "заказ" в ней есть таблица "материалы" - которые заполняются в течении определенного времени.
На каждый новый год, создается новая база. Она полностью пустая, за исключением таблицы "материалы" - ее нужно импортировать в новую базу. Возможно ли так. Или проще создать отдельную базу данных "материалы"?

Comment: `INSERT INTO db1.table (column1, column2,...) SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM db2.table;
 `

Comment: *Или проще создать отдельную базу данных "материалы"?* А как ты будешь хранить историю? Как определишь, что было в таблице материалов 2 года назад? Впрочем, если это не требуется, то отдельная база с таблицей материалов - вполне нормальное решение..

Comment: Сделать скрипт для создания новой БД по старой, который создаст БД, возьмет дамп таблиц (а некоторых и вместе с данными) и засунет в новую БД.